# How to rebuild a TListView but keep the scroll information?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-2009

In `TListView` there is a bug: when you are in `vsReport` mode with `GroupView` set and try to insert a item, it is displayed last in the group not where you inserted. The problem is debated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076861/adding-or-inserting-an-item-to-a-tlistview-always-adds-it-to-the-end-when-groupv). There are a few answers but none of them work. So, I think the only solution is to rebuild the entire list every time you insert a item. It's not simple but I think I can do it. But there is a big problem. If the scroll window is in the middle of the list and I rebuild the list, it send me back to the begining. It is possible to keep somehow the scroll information ?

I tried this:

```
procedure TNutrientsForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var ix,iy:Integer;
begin
 ix:= NList.ViewOrigin.X;
 iy:= NList.ViewOrigin.Y;
 NList.Items.BeginUpdate;
 RefreshList;
 NList.Scroll(ix, iy);
 NList.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

... but in `vsReport` mode you can only scroll in multiple of row height, so it does not position me exactly where it is supposed to.

*Anyway, if you have an answer too for the problem in the link above, you can post it there and I will be verry happy. I worked for 3 days on this and I have not found a solution. That question is 9 years old. Maybe we can try again.*

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831250) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629795) help?

Comment: At the first sight I could not make it work, but I will study it further. I think `GroupView:=true` it mess up everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to move inserted items to the correct position?

There's actually no need to [**rebuild list view**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5982680/8041231) to workaround [**the original issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1076861/8041231). It's the problem of the Windows list view control (it can be reproduced even when inserting items in a raw API way by using the [**LVM_INSERTITEM**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107(v=vs.85).aspx) message, for example).

Luckily, Delphi list view item objects are holding correct index values (of the intended placement in the control), so what remains is reordering the items in the Windows control by them. And that can be done by custom sorting. For example you can write a helper method like this:

```
type
  TListViewHelper = class helper for TListView
  public
    function FixItemsOrder: Boolean;
  end;

function FixComparer(lParam1, lParam2, lParamSort: LPARAM): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := TListItem(lParam1).Index - TListItem(lParam2).Index;
end;

function TListViewHelper.FixItemsOrder: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Boolean(SendMessage(Handle, LVM_SORTITEMS, 0, LPARAM(@FixComparer)));
end;
```

And whenever you insert an item (or multiple items), call such method:

```
var
  ListItem: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListItem := ListView1.Items.Insert(0);
    ListItem.Caption := 'Item 1';
    ListItem.GroupID := 0;

    ListItem := ListView1.Items.Insert(0);
    ListItem.Caption := 'Item 2';
    ListItem.GroupID := 0;

    ListItem := ListView1.Items.Insert(0);
    ListItem.Caption := 'Item 3';
    ListItem.GroupID := 0;

    ListView1.FixItemsOrder;
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is unbelievable ! It's not just a fix, it's a work of art. At least for me. I never thought that this bug can be so easily fixed. I worked on it for 3 days without any luck. Thank you so much, Victoria !

Comment: You're welcome! Well, maybe Microsoft fix this one day :) Actually, after I wrote the first version and searched the web, I found that even [people from .NET](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e13c25da-1eae-42ce-bb57-9e4422407cf1/inserting-items-at-specific-index-in-listviews-c-net-20) used item sorting in the end.

Comment: So this is a bug from the operating system, not from the Delphi ? My software will be affected if the bug will be corrected some day ?

Comment: Yes, it is an OS control issue. Without using any Delphi class, I've tried to insert an item, with a group ID filled by using `LVM_INSERTITEM` message and the result was the same; the item was added at the last position in the group. And no, fix of this issue should not be a problem for this workaround (you will just perform an extra sorting with no real effect because all the items will be already on correct positions).

Comment: The point is that Delphi knows the correct indices of the items (and stores them in the `TListItem.Index` property). It's just the OS list view control who inserts items ignoring them. So the only trick is that we poke the OS control asking for sort according to correct indices stored by Delphi. Hence if one day MS fixes the control, the indices will match with Delphi and effectively no sorting happens (will run, but nothing happens).